# Using Excel, how do I extract the date from a string?

Tags: excel-formula

DEC 4 DEC 5 SPORT LIFE $31.49

DEC 25 DEC 28 BESTBUY EGIFTCARD 877-850-1977 $35.00

I want to have columns 2 as:

DEC 4

DEC 25

Column 3 as:

DEC 5

DEC 28

[image]

Edit: I have uploaded the image. I want to somehow achieve column B and C.
Notice that sometimes date is DEC 4 or could be DEC 14.
(Ignore the period. I did that to quickly not have auto format)

And yes, date is always first 2 groups.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking. can you add a screenshot of current format and another screenshot of  how you want. ( use dummy data for both screenshots. don't screenshot your real excel file)

Comment: is it always the first two groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B1 and copy over one column and down the length of the data:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*198+1,198))
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet thanks! I understand, you used the space as a delimiter